# Why can't I call getters and setters of an Object in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, file, arraylist, randomaccessfile

I have a class called Game that is modelled after a video game. I also have another class called GameList which extends ArrayList. What this class is supposed to do is be a list of Games, and each Game in the GameList will be written to a Random Access File.

```
public void writeRecord(Game game1) {

}
```

From my main class I call this writeRecord method and pass it a Game object. But when I do so I cannot get the properties of the Game object at all. What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
public void writeRecord(Game game1) {
    String title = game1.getTitle();
    String developer = game1.getDeveloper();
}
```

And after that write them to the Random Access File using `file.writeChar(title);` But when I try to call these getters it says "cannot find symbol, where Game is a type-variable."

Could anyone point me in the right direction or let me know why this happens? Not sure what to do from here and I'm getting quite frustrated.

Comment: you would need  to post a mvce. Search for the term. Why do you need to extend ArrayList?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]? Which symbol are you referring to?

Comment: When you strip down your code for posting, you need to leave enough of the right parts that we can actually run it and reproduce the error. Your bug is hidden somewhere in code you haven't shown it. We can only guess as to what it is.

Comment: did you create these getters for the Game class?

Comment: You probably defined your class as `class GameList<Game> extends ArrayList<Game>`, instead of `class GameList extends ArrayList<Game>`. But anyway, do NOT extend ArrayList. Just use a regular ArrayList, without extending it.

Comment: @JBNizet Ha. Yeah, that's what it was. I knew it was something stupid like that, thank you. Could you tell me why not to extend ArrayList though? Only asking because that's the way my professor taught us that way. Thanks again.

Comment: Collections aren't really designed to be subclassed. Subclassing and overriding collection methods leads to buggy or fragile code that relies on undocumented implementation details of the parent class. For example, if you override add(), should you, or should you not also implement addAll()? Does addAll() internally calls add(), or does it not? Why are you extending ArrayList in the first place?

Comment: @JBNizet As per his assignment requirements. I would just have the ArrayList as a data member, but for some reason he will take marks off if it is not extended. Doesn't really make sense, but yeah.

Comment: For your information (and your teacher's information): read that: http://jtechies.blogspot.fr/2012/07/item-16-favor-composition-over.html. This is from a book called "Effective Java", written by Joshua Bloch, who is also the designer of the Java collections.